# Randomized issues with HttpResponseMessage being Unable to connect to remote host

Tags: c#, .net, httpresponse

#### Problem

I am working with .NET and C#. I am parsing a list of messages through a `foreach` loop to send these messages one-by-one (as per endpoint requirements) to a target endpoint as such:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(Json.Convert.SerializeObject(item), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(uriLink, content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

However, when I send the messages through, I am getting inconsistent results in which one of three things happen:

**1)** Message is sent successfully

**2)** Message errors and returns with: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond"

**3)** Message errors and returns with: "unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

I cannot figure out for the life of me what is wrong or why it fails. I have considered that it could be proxy issues with our system, but don't know how to apply a bypass to the above response message.

To further exasperate the issue, the target endpoint in question is not within the same environment nor does my team have access to it. But to give a better understanding of what is happening, the basic structure of the services in question is:

`Endpoint A Sends Msgs -> System Receives and Parses Msgs -> System Sends Msgs to Appropriate Endpoint -> Endpoint B (target) Receives Msgs`

In my tests, I have tried sending as few as 5 messages to as many as 120 messages, but the results are never the same, often varying from: all failing, roughly half failing, a few failing, or none failing.

I have also looked through several posts and other forums, but most are about `HttpRequestMessage` only, not close enough to my problem to be workable, or are unanswered problems.

#### Question

Does anyone know what could cause these sporadic problems and how best to troubleshoot/resolve them in such a situation?

Comment: This looks like either network connection problem or remote server is overloaded or remote server tries to protect itself agains DDoS attacks. Do you experience packet loss when pinging remote server? Can you confirm that remote server does not limit number of requests per second (exceeded by your application)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think there is a way to ping the target endpoint. The only thing we have about that endpoint is an api call and the format the call needs to be in. Unless you know of a way to do so with an api call (that doesn't require additional software)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what prevents you from pinging remote server - Can't you just call from command line (preferably from computer where your program is running something like `ping -n 50 api_hostname` where `api_hostname` is hostname from `uriLink` variable? Of course server might be configured to refuse ping, but at least you can try.

Comment: @Ňuf That's the problem. The endpoint does not belong to us and the only information given is how to structure the response message. Basically, Our system receives messages from one endpoint -> our system repackages those messages as a new response which is sent to the target endpoint -> target endpoint then handles the messages

Comment: Even if target endpoint doesn't belong to you, you can still try to ping it. If endpoint doesn't respond to ping at all (100% packet loss) then ping is probably disabled on endpoint and will not help you much. But if packet loss is 0%, then you know that problem is probably not network-related and you can focus on investigating other possible causes. If packet loss it more then 0% and less than 100%, then your problem is caused by unreliable network connection.

Comment: @Ňuf Could you provide an example of an API ping? I do not understand how to do this. I am only familiar with pinging a PC Name or IP Address

Comment: Of course you cannot ping API (because API uses HTTP(s) protocol and ping uses ICMP protocol), sorry if it wasn't clear from my previous posts. But as I wrote above, you can ping server that is hosting this API. For example if API URL (value in `uriLink` variable) is "http://some.host.com/api/v1/api_method_name?parameter=foo" you can ping it with command `ping -n 50 some.host.com`